# Get date from images

Tags: javascript, electron, multer

I'm building an app for uploading images and I'm having problem when I need to get date when was image uploaded. Images will be uploaded randomly so date must be equal to date of upload. 
I'm working app with electron and for image uploading I'm using multer.

Here is my code for image gallery where I get uploaded images to image gallery. If anyone has some idea how it should be, I would be gratefull for reply.

```
// Image gallery
    app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    let images = getImagesFromDir(path.join(__dirname, 'public/uploads'));
    let time = new Date(images.lastModified); //here I'm trying to get date
    res.render('gallery', { title: 'Galerija slik', images: images, time: time })
});

// dirPath: target image directory
function getImagesFromDir(dirPath) {

    // All iamges holder, defalut value is empty
    let allImages = [];

    // Iterator over the directory
    let files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

    // Iterator over the files and push jpg and png images to allImages array.
    for (file of files) {
        let fileLocation = path.join(dirPath, file);
        var stat = fs.statSync(fileLocation);
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
            getImagesFromDir(fileLocation); // process sub directories
        } else if (stat && stat.isFile() && ['.jpg', '.png'].indexOf(path.extname(fileLocation)) != -1) {
            allImages.push('uploads/'+file); // push all .jpf and .png files to all images 
        }
    }

    // return all images in array formate
    return allImages;
}
```

And this is my HTML code

```
      <div id="content">

        <h2 class="text-center"><%= title %></h2>

    <div id="filters">
        <a href="#" id="newer" class="selected">Newer</a>
        <a href="#" id="older">Older</a>
    </div>
    <div id="posts">

        <% for(let image of images) {%>
            <article class="post">
                <figure>
                    <a href="<%= image %>" data-fancybox="1"><img src="<%= image %>" /></a>
                </figure>
                <time><%= time %></time>
        </article>
          <% } %>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you wanted to get the last modified date of each image.

```
// Image gallery
    app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    let images = getImagesFromDir(path.join(__dirname, 'public/uploads'));
    res.render('gallery', { title: 'Galerija slik', images: images })
});

// dirPath: target image directory
function getImagesFromDir(dirPath) {

    // All iamges holder, defalut value is empty
    let allImages = [];

    // Iterator over the directory
    let files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

    // Iterator over the files and push jpg and png images to allImages array.
    for (file of files) {
        let fileLocation = path.join(dirPath, file);
        var stat = fs.statSync(fileLocation);
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
            getImagesFromDir(fileLocation); // process sub directories
        } else if (stat && stat.isFile() && ['.jpg', '.png'].indexOf(path.extname(fileLocation)) != -1) {
            allImages.push({path: 'uploads/'+file, lastModifiedDate: stat.mtime}); // push all .jpf and .png files to all images 
        }
    }

    // return all images in array formate
    return allImages;
}
```

And html should be updated like the below one.

```
<div id="posts"> <% for(let image of images) {%> <article class="post"> <figure> <a href="<%= image.path %>" data-fancybox="1"><img src="<%= image.path %>" /></a> </figure> <time><%= image.lastModifiedDate %></time> </article> <% } %> </div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn’t work for me. When I replace old code with this it doesnt load any images. Goal for this program is that it shows uploaded images and under them display date of last modified.

Comment: Updated the answer. You have to use the path and lastModifiedDate properties in each image

Comment: Works perfecf. Thanks man. If u'll ever be in Slovenia, contact me, I'll buy lunch 

Comment: "Works perfect" means alot for me. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I just have one more question. Now it displays the date as Tue Feb 14 2017 15:14:37 GMT+0100 (CET). How could I reformat date to Tue Feb 14 2017